# Linux user-space ELF loader after fork extremely strange behavior

Tags: linux, fork, elf, ptrace, execve

Consider the following code (revisited to compile due to public demand :):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static FILE* logfile = 0;

int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * envp[]) {
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { /* child */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) == -1)
        assert(0 && "ptrace traceme failed");

    /* signal the parent that the child is ready */
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
    execve("a.out", argv, envp);
} else { /* parent */
    int status = 0, ret = 0;

    if ((logfile = fopen("log","a+")) == 0)
        assert(0 && "failed to open logfile");

    struct stat logfile_stat_buf;
    if (stat("log", &logfile_stat_buf) != 0)
        assert(0 && "failed to stat logfile");

    /* sync the parent and the child */
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL | __WCLONE) < 0)
        assert(0 && "waiting on child failed");


    ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);

    while (waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL | __WCLONE) > 0) {
        /* syscall entry */
        struct user_regs_struct regs;
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
        /* check to see if it's a mmap call
         * void *mmap2(void *addr, size_t length, int prot,int flags, int fd, off_t pgoffset); 
         */
        printf("Child entereing a syscall %d\n", regs.orig_eax);
        if (regs.orig_eax == SYS_mmap2) {
            /* stat the file for the inode */
            int fd = regs.edi;
            struct stat stat_buf;
            if ((fstat(fd, &stat_buf) == 0) && (stat_buf.st_ino == logfile_stat_buf.st_ino))
                assert(0 && "child trying to mmap parent inode");
        }

        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
        waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL | __WCLONE);
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);
        /* syscall exit */
        printf("Child exiting a syscall %d\n", regs.orig_eax);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
    }

    if (fclose(logfile) != 0)
        assert(0 && "failed to close logfile");
}

return 0;
}
```

The a.out program is a simple main() { return 0; } program.

If you compile and run this code, you will see that the child process tried to mmap() the file opened by the **parent** fopen("log") call. You will see this by the failing assertion.

I researched further and found that this happens during loading of the child process.

This is strange for 2 reasons:

1. the child should not be aware of the fopen() call at all since it happened after the fork()
2. why would the loader try to mmap this file? its not even an executable.

I looked around dl-load.c in glibc but saw nothing that should invoke this sort of behaviour.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I edited your code to add relevant includes and 2nd argument to fopen

Comment: Edited to fix the fix. (;->,)

Comment: Can you show the raw 'tracing' output? Are you using strace or something else?

Comment: I don't observe your behavior with `strace`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, please do not 'correct' the code in questions. Often if the code is incorrect, it indicates the OP is leaving out something important (ie, they tried redacting but cut out the part that really matters to answer their question). It's best just to ask the OP for the real source code (indentation changes and formatting is ok though!)

Comment: @nimi, with that in mind, please provide the complete code you're actually running.

Comment: What is `a.out`? If it's the program itself, then of course the child is going to read `log`.

Comment: @nimi: Please improve your question till at least your code compiles with `gcc -Wall -g` without warnings, and tell us how exactly you compile, and what is `a.out` (is it the binary executable of your program)?

Comment: @nimi: See my answer. Your tracing code contains a bug, which we would never have even guessed at if you hadn't posted that code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a buggy code, the issue lied in the fact that i interpreted the child file descriptor under the parent context. The correct thing to do it track the child open() calls and keep a mapping of filename to child fd.

thanks to nneonneo for helping me figure this out.

Comment: About your deleted question: errno location is libc- and arch- specific. There is a some info about its location in threads like "how to print thread's errno from gdb", like [here](http://forum.soft32.com/linux/gdb-user-command-hunt-errno-ftopict420867.html). So, you should know how to compute address to be returned by `pthread_self()` (search for THREAD_SELF macro in glibc sources) and then use it with offset to find errno's address.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is buggy; the behaviour you observed was a result of the program misinterpreting the trace data.

Running your program, we can *immediately* see a problem in the first five lines:

```
Child entereing a syscall 11
Child exiting a syscall 11
Child entereing a syscall 11
Child exiting a syscall 45
Child entereing a syscall 45
```

Say what? According to your tracing program, syscall 45 *exited* before it was *entered*, which is clearly a misinterpretation of the syscall trace. Therefore, from that point onwards, *all* of your tracing data is invalid because you actually trace the state post-syscall. It's not surprising, then, that you concluded that the child opened `log` (FWIW, the output of your program on *my* machine did not show this behaviour, but since the data is misinterpreted anything could happen).

So why does syscall 11 (`execve`) appear three times? The answer is in `man 2 ptrace`:

> Also, all subsequent calls to `execve(2)` by this process will cause a SIGTRAP to be sent to it, giving the parent a chance to gain control before the new program begins execution. A process probably shouldn't make this request if its parent isn't expecting to trace it. (pid, addr, and data are ignored.)

Basically, when you see an `execve` syscall, you have to perform an extra `ptrace` call to resume the child after a successful call returns (see, for example, how [this minimal trace example](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/ptrace.c) does it). Once you do this, the incorrect `mmap` call should disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The enter\exit thing wasn't really the issue here, but i apologize for the bug. I will investigate further using that piece of code you gave me.

So you say the assertion did not fail on your machine? very interesting.

Comment: Actually, the enter/exit thing *is* the problem. You are misinterpreting the `mmap` system call arguments. The assertion didn't fail on my machine, almost certainly because of random accident.